# Getting scroll position of element ID with window.scrollY

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app has `overflow: hidden` applied to the `body` for reasons of tranformations. This left the issue of not being able to register the scroll position of `scrollY` as scrolling happens in child components.

How can I apply `window.scrollY` or similar to register the scroll position of `<div id="innerContainer">`?

Here is a snippet of where one `scroll` `addEventListener` is creating a class on scroll. Problem is without registering the `scrollY` I cannot add the event.

```
componentDidMount () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleHeaderStuck);
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleHeaderStuck);
}
```

or

```
handleHeaderStuck() {
  console.log('scrollPos', window.scrollY)
  if (window.scrollY === 0 && this.state.isStuck === true) {
      this.setState({isStuck: false});
  }
  else if (window.scrollY !== 0 && this.state.isStuck !== true) {
      this.setState({isStuck: true});
  }
}
```

and the general layout of is...

```
render() {
  return (
    <main className={this.state.isStuck ? 'header-stuck' : ''}>
      <div id="container">
        <header />
        <div id="innerContainer">...</div>
        <footer />
      </div>
    </main>
```

Update - after applying the answer submitted by **Kingdaro**:

Screenshot of console using the code submitted by Kingdaro that registers the `scrollPos` change but not the actual position

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) should do the job here. Also make sure to unregister the event listener when the component unmounts, to avoid memory leaks.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  innerContainer = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.innerContainer.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleHeaderStuck)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.innerContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleHeaderStuck)
  }

  // using a class property here so the `this` context remains properly bound
  handleHeaderStuck = () => {
    console.log('div scroll position:', this.innerContainer.scrollTop)
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="innerContainer" ref={el => (this.innerContainer = el)} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Kingdaro, thank you. Unfortunately, whilst this is now registering the scroll position change, each is showing as 0. I have added a screenshot above for you to see. Any suggestions to fix this? I feel like your solution is almost there.

Comment: Is your code still printing the `window.scrollY` instead of that of the div? Which would be `this.innerContainer.scrollTop` if I remember correctly. Sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: I had `console.log('scrollPos', window.scrollY)` added to print to console.  I attached a gif to show this better in my question. I shall have a go at your suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: Did you mean to replace `this.innerContainer` with `this.innerContainer.scrollTop` from inside the `div id="innerContainer"`?

Comment: I mean to replace `window.scrollY` with `this.innerContainer.scrollTop`. The window's scroll position doesn't change, but the div's does, so you have to get the scroll position of the div. I'll update my answer

Comment: That makes perfect sense and works a treat. Thank you for your time.