# Can't get scroll position using `window.scrollY` or `window.pageYOffset`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### Problem

I need to get the scroll position so that I can toggle the tooltip position according to it.

Here is how my tooltip looks:

[image: tooltip]

But when I scroll down, I want it to toggle downwards but the desired is not happening right now: toggling upwards

[image]

#### Approach to the problem

I tried using `window.scrollY` and `window.pageYOffset` to get the scroll position but it keeps logging it as `0` no matter how much I scroll.

#### Possible solution

I tried referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563924/getting-scroll-position-of-element-id-with-window-scrolly)
but removing the `height: 100%` property doesn't work for me.

#### Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import glossary from '../Documentation/glossary'

class Tooltip extends Component {
  state = {
    hover: false,
    timeout: null,
    width: 400,
    margin: -70,
    pointMargin: -15
  }

  tooltipWidthEval = () => {
    const markdownBody = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown-body')[0]
    const maxWidth = markdownBody.offsetLeft + markdownBody.clientWidth
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-container')[0]
    const tooltipWidth = container.offsetLeft + this.state.width
    if (tooltipWidth > maxWidth) {
      this.setState({
        margin: -340,
        pointMargin: 260
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        margin: -70,
        pointMargin: -15
      })
    }
  }

  hoverIn = () => {
    console.log(window.scrollY)
    if (this.state.interval) {
      clearTimeout(this.state.interval)
      this.setState(
        {
          interval: null,
          hover: true
        },
        this.tooltipWidthEval
      )
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          hover: true
        },
        this.tooltipWidthEval
      )
    }
  }

  hoverOut = () => {
    this.setState({
      interval: setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          hover: false
        })
      }, 100)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props
    let header = ''
    let description = ''
    glossary.contents.forEach(glossaryItem => {
      if (glossaryItem.match.includes(text)) {
        header = glossaryItem.name
        description = glossaryItem.desc
      }
    })
    return (
      <>
        <HighlightedText
          onMouseOver={this.hoverIn}
          onMouseLeave={this.hoverOut}
        >
          {text}
        </HighlightedText>
        {this.state.hover && (
          <TooltipContainer
            className="tooltip-container"
            onMouseOver={this.hoverIn}
            onMouseLeave={this.hoverOut}
          >
            <TooltipText
              margin={this.state.margin}
              width={this.state.width}
              pointMargin={this.state.pointMargin}
            >
              <div className="header">{header}</div>
              <ReactMarkdown source={description} />
            </TooltipText>
          </TooltipContainer>
        )}
      </>
    )
  }
}

const HighlightedText = styled.span`
  border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
`

const TooltipContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 300000000;
  background-color: white;
`

const TooltipText = styled.div`
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d5da;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 90%;
  margin-left: ${props => props.margin || -70}px;
  width: ${props => props.width || 400}px;

  &:after,
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: ${props => props.pointMargin || -15}px;
  }

  &:after {
    left: 10%;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  &:before {
    left: 10%;
    border-width: 11px;
    border-color: #d1d5da transparent transparent transparent;
  }

  .header {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
`

export default Tooltip
```

P.S. I would like if the problem is solved using javascript only since the project doesn't use `jQuery`.

Comment: What about scrollTop

Comment: @super scrollTop also doesn't work for me.

Comment: scrollTop should do the trick

Comment: How and when do you call `window.scrollY` in your script ? Can’t help without code. Also `scrollTop` isn’t part of any specification (unlike `window.scrollY`), so I don’t recommend using it at all.

Comment: @KawaLo Please check it now. I have added the code as well. I tried to get `window.scrollY` in `hoverIn` function.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that you are not actually scrolling the complete page, but have a fixed-height element in there somewhere with `overflow:scroll` (or auto) applied. So you need to read the scroll offset from that element, not window.

Comment: One workaround could be to use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method on an element such as `<html>`: `document.querySelector('html').getBoundingClientRect().top`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got this right you're actually scrolling a container (like a `div` or something similar) and not the page itself. In this case you can get the scroll offset with `scrollTop` as mentioned in the comments before.

**BUT** You need to get that property for the element you're scrolling (**NOT** `window.scrollTop`). So if your content is in a div you need to get the `scrollTop` property from that element. Here is a working example where I get the scroll position from an element:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
 console.log(container.scrollTop);
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
#content {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So I have a div which has a class called `markdown-body`. When I logged `document.getElementsByClassName('markdown-body')[0].scrollHeight`, it displayed `2855`. But when I scroll it and log `document.getElementsByClassName('markdown-body')[0].scrollTop`, its value remain 0.
This is the page I'm talking about: https://dvc.org/doc/commands-reference/version

Comment: Okay, I have figured it out. I used `document.getElementById('bodybag').scrollTop` to get the scroll position  and it works! But I don't know why.

Comment: Well because `window.scrollY` is the scroll for the body element (afaik, don't quote me on that). `[element].scrollTop` gives you the scroll offset to the top. And just for your information `scrollHeight` gives you the full height that could be scrolled. If my answer is correct, please accept it :) otherwise Ask me and I'll try to help you. btw nice looking website